# How to optimize remote desktop connection over local network to be virtually lagless?

Tags: windows, networking, macos, router, remote-desktop

**What I'm looking for:**
Suggestions on where to look, what to look for, what types of things to diagnose, etc to help drive me in the direction of a "lagless" local remote desktop connection. Additional links for reference materials, videos, etc are all welcome.

**What I'm not looking for:** I don't expect to see an answer like "Download XYZ and that'll do it." I understand this can be a fairly broad subject involving more research, hard work, etc and I'm not expecting too much.

---

I have two machines at home:

**Router:** [ASUS AC 1900](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FB45SI4)

**Machine A:** Windows 10 Enterprise / 64 GB RAM / 8 TB M.2. SSD / GeForce 2070 Super / Intel i9-9900k / Ethernet to Router

**Machine B:** MacBook Pro 15" 2015 Edition updated to Catalina, connected to WiFi over 5G

I can update hardware / software, but using WiFi on a mobile computer is required. The goal here is to seamlessly interact with my desktop tower from anywhere in the house. Ordinarily, I would be within 20 feet of it and that should be the assumption for any optimizations suggested.

---

I'm regularly connecting to my Windows machine from my laptop using Microsoft Remote Desktop. It works pretty well, but it can have a slight noticeable lag. I'm wondering what steps / optimizations I need to make to inch closer toward a native lagless feeling.

My thought is that considering the home network, ethernet connection, powerful PC, etc that there must be a way where I can get close.

I'm open to learning about additional software, configuration changes, additional hardware changes, etc. I've been programming since 1996, so I'm comfortable doing most things; but some of this network specific stuff is a bit out of my wheelhouse.

**The Question:** What types of things should I work on from Machine A / Machine B / Router / Other perspective to eliminate lag possibilities?

Thank you!

Comment: What operations have "noticeable lag"? I use a remote machine over a VPN link across the Internet and the only "lag" I see is due to the machine being memory starved and the nature of a virtual machine on a host with multiple VMs all needing disk access. When stuff is loaded clicks appear as quickly as can be expected. If you want reliable operation then dump the WiFi.

Comment: Some of the lag might have to do with the mac client.  Have you tried it from another Windows machine?  The engineer that writes both clients is primarily a Windows programmer.

Comment: Maybe you can first considering the group policy configuration to improve the remote desktop experience. Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Remote Session Environment

Comment: @Mokubai Primarily in basic functions, like moving the mouse around, clicks, and typing. It's not like it's very clearly skipping frames, but it feels slower like if your mouse movement was reduced from FAST to MEDIUM; you know? It's a small amount of lag, but still noticeable.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I have not tried it from another Windows machine yet.

Comment: @Seven I'll look at some of that.

Comment: I run similar Mac>Win RDP sessions here with no appreciable lag over wired ethernet. I'd always eliminate wifi as a first step.

Comment: @Tetsujin Eliminating the wifi on one side isn't a possibility; so optimizations that include WiFi

Comment: You should include that detail in your question. To me, eliminating wifi is always the first thing to do, not the last. Wifi is a burst technology, not good for real-time.